# get difference in time in HH:MM format php

Tags: php, time, datediff

how can i get this to output

HH:MM format?

```
 $to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");  <--AM
 $from_time = strtotime("2008-12-14 8:21:00");  <-- PM
 $stat = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). "min";
```

what i got from this is 1299 mins

but i cant figure out how to make it output

21h:41m

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, `8:21:00` will be interpreted as 8AM unless you specified otherwise using `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

To work out time differences, use `DateTime::diff()`:

```
$to = new DateTime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from = new DateTime("2008-12-14 8:21:00");

$stat = $to->diff($from); // DateInterval object

echo $stat->format('%Hh:%Im');
```

This will display the hour/minute difference between the two times, but only up to 24 hours.

If you need more than 24 hours, you should do the following:

```
$hours   = $stat->days * 24 + $stat->h;
$minutes = $stat->i;

printf('%02sh:%sm', $hours, $minutes);
```

Comment: This one also does not return correct value when there is more than 24 hours between dates

Comment: The $stat object is an instance of [DateInterval](http://au.php.net/DateInterval), check the docs on how to extract days/months/years.

Comment: So please remove/edit `format` line since it does not include any info about days and produces misleading result.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to include AM and PM in your date strings, otherwise `2008-12-14 8:21:00` will be interpreted as `8:21 AM`

Now the difference between two dates is `2019` that is 33h:19m, you cant' have t with standard date formats, since they support only 24h clock. You should keep `$stat` as integer, and display it with `sprintf` like like this:

```
echo sprintf('%02dh:%02dm', $stat/60, $stat%60);
```