# time difference in hours and min in php HH:MM format for d/m/Y - h:ia

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get difference in time in HH:MM format php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002723/get-difference-in-time-in-hhmm-format-php)

my time format is d/m/Y - h:ia

example output is 21/10/2012 - 03:49pm

I'm using this code to calculate the difference between $from and $to

```
 $to = strtotime("21/10/2012 - 10:30pm");
 $from = strtotime("22/10/2012 - 8:30am");
 $stat = date("H\h:i\m", abs($to - $from));
```

but I'm alwys getting an incorrect value

for the example above I got an output of 16h:00m but it should be 10h:00m

is there a much more efficient and effective way to do this?

Comment: The result of date() depends on your time zone.
Use gmtime() instead to avoid this.

Comment: please don't ask same question twice, there are possible answers in your previous question.

Comment: time date format from that question is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format is incorrect and unrecognized by [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (see the third note) I suspect that your timezone is GMT-8 and you will always get 16h from dates in this format.

You have to convert manually this date to format recognized by php in order to do some calculations

Comment: got the answer thankss for the  tip!

Answer (score 1):

logout:

> if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
> date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
>
> ```
> $from = $_SESSION['loginT'];
> $to = date('m/d/Y  h:i A');
> $diff_seconds  = strtotime($to) - strtotime($from);
> $stat = floor($diff_seconds/3600).'H:'.floor(($diff_seconds%3600)/60).'M';
> ```

from login:

```
$_SESSION['loginT'] = date('m/d/Y  h:i A');
```

sample output:

```
21/10/2012 - 06:37pm    21/11/2012 - 06:07pm        23H:30M
```