# PHP - Show time elapsed between two hours

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have four fields, using those I display the elapsed time between them.
This is my php code:

```
// Days elapsed from the moment of the creation to the date of the visit
$date1   = $ticket->date_at;
$date2   = $ticket->visit_date;
$diff    = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

// Specific time elapsed between the dates, (days, months and years)
$years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

// Hours elapsed
$horallamada   = strtotime($ticket->time_at);
$horavis = strtotime($ticket->visit_hour_in);
$horasal   = strtotime($ticket->visit_hour_out);
$hdiff   = $horallamada   - $horasal;
$hvisdiff = $horallamada   - $horavis;
$hsolution = $horavis - $horasal;

// printing of the time elapsed to answer the ticket
printf("<p>This ticket was answered in ");  
echo gmdate("H:i", abs($hvisdiff)); printf(" hours.</p>");
   
// printing of the time elapsed to solve the ticket
printf("<p>This ticket was solved in ");
echo gmdate("H:i", abs($hsolution)); printf(" hours.</p>");
       
// total time elapsed calculation
printf("This ticket was closed in %d years, %d months, %d days and \n", $years, $months, $days);
echo gmdate("H:i", abs($hdiff)); printf(" hours after the date of creation.");
```

`$hvisdiff`, `$hsolution` and `$hdiff` will return the difference as "02:36", that would be, 02 ***hours*** and 36 ***minutes***.

How can I make it show like this?

Like:

> This ticket was answered in 02 hours and 36 minutes
>
> This ticket was solved in 01 hours and 6 minutes
>
> This ticket was closed x years, x months, x days and 03 hours and 46 minutes after the date of creation.

I tried the following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002723/get-difference-in-time-in-hhmm-format-php) tutorial, however, it wouldn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please remember `Carbon` is just a wrapper for the standard PHP `DateTime` class.

Comment: I know, that why I want to know how can I achieve it without it. I will take a look at the question pinned above.